# Powerapps : Filtering records from sharepoint with records inside

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

I'm trying to make to make and application where i will choose a projet name in a dropdown list (1 sharepoint list), then on others screens, i want to show some informations (for examples, risks) filtered on the selected project. those risks information are in another SP List with project filed declared as lookup column.

When i tried to filter on the second screen on the selected project, it told me it's a track and i can't filter :
[image]

Should be a syntax problem probably, but could'nt find it

Comment: When you hover on the expression with the squiggly line, what is the error that you see as a tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Risk data source and filter on that.

`Filter('Risk_SP_Table_Name',ProjectID=dropdownSelector.Selected.ID)`

Something like this. Hope this helps